# White Gaussian Noise: a reality or fantasy?

Tags: signal-detection, estimation

White noise has infinite variance, whereas Gaussian random variable must have some finite-variance to exist. How do two disjoint phenomena co-exist?

Help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Definitely a duplicate of the question linked to by pichenettes, and, as discussed in the reference cited there, white noise is a fantasy, but a very useful (and for many, a very lucrative) one to have and to hold.

Comment: This is not a duplication. This question is about the difference between the "Variance" of White Process vs. the Variance of Random Variable. I vote to reopen as the discussion can and should be interesting.